# Are there universality classes not found through a Ginzburg-Landau like free energy expansion

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, field-theory, renormalization, effective-field-theory

Usually the real free energy of a system is too complex to be exactly computed, thus one either expands it in power/gradient series or simply builds it from symmetry considerations. For example:
$$F[\phi] = \displaystyle{\int \mathrm{d}x}\sum_{n}a_n\phi^n+b_n\nabla\phi^n +c_n(\nabla\phi)^n+\sum_md_{n, m}\phi^m\nabla \phi^n+\dots$$

Then, one justifies that this approach is enough to describe the macroscopic part of the system because at large lenght scale, almost all the terms will be irrelevant (in the RG sense) except a few low-order one.

Through the scope of the RG, one is lead to believe that, an expansion in power is enough to characterise every possible different macroscopic phenomenon. That is, every possible universality classes present in the nature can be described with a power expansion. Is it true or are there some universality classes that can't be found through a Ginzburg-Landau free energy?

---

Note: Out of equilibrium, we can find new universality classes by relaxing the "analyticity" requirement on the free energy, by for example doing an expansion in half-power of the order parameter. See for example [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.04777)!

Comment: G-L paradigm fails miserably for integer/fractional quantum hall effect and other topological-type phase transitions, right? Another example: can you apply G-L to QCD confinement phase transition or the quark-gluon plasma?  I think G-L also failed miserably in this regard.

Comment: @MadMax Ok, thanks for your answer! That's interesting (Add on top of that, that I don't know a thing about quantum stuff)! Do you think there might be a classical system for which GL fails?

Comment: There is no such thing as "classical GL system". The "order parameter" $\phi$
 in a typical GL scenario is always an effective representation of some quantum effect. For instance, $\phi$ could be either the quantum expectation value of quantum spin in the case of magnetic material or quantum cooper pair in the case of superconductivity.

Comment: I disagree with @MadMax's last comment about G-L theory being quantum. You can use G-L theory to describe the classical Ising transition. An example of a classical phase transition where G-L fails is the BKT transition.

Comment: I guess that by classical GL, I meant a "coarse graining" of some classical microscopic hamiltonian (because you could always say, 
with ising, that you are building an effective theory of quantum spin.). Anyway  I like the BKT example but I think we can't really talk about a continuous transition for this PT?